# Test submodule from inside that submodule

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, git-submodules

I want to write a (~unit)test for a submodule, inside that submodule. The problem is in all the `import`s that are in submodule, because normally, the program is run from the main project, that is 1 level higher. All imports have name of submodules in the definition, and can't be executed, when I run it from inside.

```
submod1:
    features.py
    constants.py
        pi=3.1415
    utils.py
        from submod1.features import feature1, feature2
        from submod1.constants import g, m, e, pi
        def func_to_test1():
        ...
        def func_to_test2():
        ...
    test.py
        from utils import func_to_test1
        def test_func():
        ...
       
submod2:
    file1.py
        from submod2.file2 import foo, bar
    file2.py
```

So I get error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'submodule1' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Which directory are you running the command from? What's the full `python -m unittest` command? (i.e. are there any arguments after `unittest`?)